# Push Notification in blackberry using UrbanAirship

Tags: blackberry, push-notification

When running client app 5.0 on blackberry I am getting response
"Push Status: urbanAirshipRegisterPIN OK (status: 200) "during registration.

But i am not able to receive any message on my device after sending notification from UrbanAirship Dashboard.

Please suggest me the proper way to implement push notification on blackberry from both 
perspectives i.e client side(Java) as well as server side(Php).

Also i want to know the is it necessary to activate BIS(Blackberry Internet Services) 
services provisioned by "mobile network service provider like airtel". Thanks.